# How do I display content grabbed from external websites?

Tags: php, html, curl, feed, mamp

How do I grab pieces of content from external websites and display them on my website? (Similar to what an RSS feed or other aggregator does).

For example, say I want to display items from another website's calendar:

**Other website:**

```
<h1>Here's our calendar:</h1>

<div class="calendar_item">
  <h2>Boston Marathon</h2>
  <p class="date">June 23, 2012</p>
  <p class="description">This marathon is 26.2 miles and lots of fun.</p>
</div>

<div class="calendar_item">    
  <h2>Irish Pub Crawl</h2>
  <p class="date">July 17, 2012</p>
  <p class="description">Shamrocks and green things are super-fun.</p>
</div>

<div class="calendar_item">
  <h2>Tim's Birthday</h2>
  <p class="date">August 25, 2012</p>
  <p class="description">It's Tim's birthday, yo.</p>
</div>
```

**My website:**

```
<h1>Here's a feed of some calendar items from someone else's website:</h1>

<div class="event_title">Boston Marathon</div>
<div class="event_date">June 23, 2012</div>
<div class="event_description">This marathon is 26.2 miles and lots of fun.</div>

<div class="event_title">Irish Pub Crawl</div>
<div class="event_date">July 17, 2012</div>
<div class="event_description">Shamrocks and green things are super-fun.</div>

<div class="event_title">Tim's Birthday</div>
<div class="event_date">August 25, 2012</div>
<div class="event_description">It's Tim's birthday, yo.</div>
```

Here's what I've tried (using MAMP):

```
<?php

$url = "http://example.com";

$page = curl($url);

$pattern = '%
<h2>(.+?)</h2>
%i';

preg_match($pattern,$page,$matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

...which prints:

```
Array ( )
```

The tutorials/etc. I've viewed include ambiguous answers like "try cURL". This seems so simple, but I'm a stumped noob.

Thanks in advance, guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend regex for parsing HTML. PHP 5+ comes with a parser which you can use as shown below.

```
$content = file_get_contents('test.html');
$doc = 
<<<DOC
$content
DOC;
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($doc);
$h2Tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName("h2");
$pTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName("p");
foreach($h2Tags as $h2 ) {
    //do something
}

foreach($pTags as $p ) {
if($p->getAttribute("class") == "date") {
    //do something
}

}
```

$h2 is of type DOMElement. It inherits DOMNode. So you can use nodeValue property to access the values. In the above example, you can write $h2->nodeValue to access the content.

Comment: Thanks! In the "//do something" line, how do echo the content wrapped in the H2 or P tags? I tried "echo $h2;", but it didn't work. (I'm new to this stuff).

Comment: Another question, if someone has time: If each "calendar item" was wrapped in a div (as I've added above), how do I grab all three items within that parent div (the h2 and both p's) and echo them as groups? (Similar to how I kept them grouped under "My website" above).

In other words:

For each div with class "calendar_item" {
  echo h2;
  echo p (class="date);
  echo p (class="event_description");
}

I figured that wasn't worthy of creating a whole new question, but I've been looking everywhere and I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this library http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

then just:

```
foreach($dom->find('p[class=date]' as $p) {
  $date = $p->innertext;
}
```

this would give you the contents of

or you do it more globaly and dig through with stripos

```
foreach($dom->find('p') as $p) {
  if(stripos($p->class, 'date') !== false) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded the library and there's some really cool stuff I can do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for using cURL:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

and check if you are getting data before applying `preg_match`. If you get some, then it's the regex which causes your problem.